# Hidden files won't go away - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, hidden-file

I have accumulated multiple different types of software for University courses. It has now come to my attention that there are multiple (.filename) files under my Windows C://>Users>watts. I've tried to hide them with the options in the view, but to no success. It's not that big of a deal but kind of annoying seeing .filename files just sitting around not really doing anything that I know.

Thanks for any help!

[Screen shot of view options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQKa7.png)

[Screen shot of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu5DD.png)

Comment: As Mike said, you can mark a file or folder as hidden and you can uncheck a hidden file or folder at any time to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not follow the convention of hiding filenames beginning with a dot. You need to right-click the file in Explorer, select Properties and set the Hidden attribute. Then the file will be visible or hidden per the view option you have already set.

You can also set the hidden attribute (and others) at the command line, using the `attrib` command. Use `help attrib` to see its usage.